# Error while injecting EJB running on IBM websphere in spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, ejb, websphere

I was trying to inject an EJB in spring context using this:

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="reportMisBeans" business-interface="com.nsdl.sam.app.reportmis.remote.SamReportMisRemote" jndi-name="SamReportMisRemote" environment-ref="env">
</jee:remote-slsb>
<util:properties id="env">
  <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory</prop> 
  <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://172.18.75.23:2811/</prop>
</util:properties>"
```

But getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
[Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]
```

I have already kept the IBM thin EJB client jar in `classpath.`

Comment: Are you running it on WebSphere and trying to inject EJB from the same JVM, or you have your app on some third party server and trying to access remote EJB running on WebSphere?

Comment: EJB is on a remote server i.e. why i am using remote lookup.

Comment: If your client server is WebSphere, then you dont need thin client in the classpath, if it is third party in addition to ejb thin client you will need `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar`.

Comment: my client code is running on tomcat container

Comment: I had the same problem with springboot injecting ejb in ibmwebsphere [separate apps, same container, also tried with different container].  I also tried various lookup/thinclient/nothingclient etc. I can confirm in IBMWAS it does not work (Jboss works!). IBM support & forums were not useful. They usually direct you not to use Spring! Great customer service :). What I did was, expose ejb as webservice, and use springboot to connect to that webservice. I've to go through all these loops because the Client-org wants to use this IBM-beast.

Answer (score 0):

If your client container is Tomcat, you will need both jars: `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar` and `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar`. Also if security is enabled on WebSphere server and SSL is required you will need additional setup. Please refer to this page for more details [Running the IBM Thin Client for EJB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-17-0-3&lang=en)

Comment: **same exception**

The IBM Thin Client for EJB can access version 2.x and version 3.x EJB on the WebSphere Application Server using the JNDI lookup, but it cannot access version 3.x EJB through resource injection. Resource injection is supported if the client application is a Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Application Client running within the Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Application Client Container.

can you tell me whether IBM client don't support injection in spring running on tomcat.

basic lookup is working even without com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar

Comment: @BipulKumar , if basic lookup is working for you, then it is Spring issue. If you are providing factory and url, then it should use InitialContext lookup underneath not injection (@EJB). From your exception, it looks like Spring cannot find the required class - class loading problem not injection problem (maybe full stack trace would tell something more). You need to find out, why Spring is not seeing that class.